# Model.where(...).first attribute is not nil but shows nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm playing with rails console:

```
a = Event.where("location_id IS NULL")
  Event Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (start_date >= '2015-02-20' OR end_date >= '2015-02-20') AND (location_id IS NULL)
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Event id: 58, name: "BENNY GREB CLINIC w Hard Rock Cafe Warszawa", start_date: "2015-02-21", end_date: nil, location: "Hard Rock Cafe Warsaw,ul. Złota 59,Warsaw,Poland", logo_url: "https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-...", website: "", facebook: "https://www.facebook.com/events/535924839876600", created_at: "2015-02-19 17:38:29", updated_at: "2015-02-19 17:38:29", logo_file_file_name: nil, logo_file_content_type: nil, logo_file_file_size: nil, logo_file_updated_at: nil, location_id: nil>]>
```

So `location: "Hard Rock Cafe Warsaw,ul. Złota 59,Warsaw,Poland"`

But when I do:

```
2.2.0 :002 > a.first.location
```

I get

```
 => nil
```

Why?

Comment: I assume because you have a location attribute and a location association and rails is using the association.  You need to rethink your database structure

Comment: What's the output of: a.attributes

Comment: what's the output of `a.first`

Comment: @japed - it's the correct answer, I changed attribute name to `address` and it works fine. Thanks, you can write in as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a location attribute and a location association and rails is using the association. You need to rethink your database structure so they are named differently.

Answer (score 1):

As per the first comment in the question:

You might be using an active record association:

```
has_one :location
```

or

```
belongs_to :location
```

Active record will give precedence to the relation over the model attribute.

Try adding:

```
has_one/belongs_to :location, as: 'related_location'
```

To the model in order to ensure location is always defining the attribute. And you will access to the related location (using the `location_id`) using the aliased method.